# Can you explain in terms of logic gates how Babbage’s Analytical Engine worked?

Tags: computer-architecture

On a recent trip to the London Science Museum I saw [Babbage’s](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) [Analytical Engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine).

[image]

[image]

Apparently this had an ALU (or equivalent). Is the Analytical Engine binary? I can build an ALU out of logic gates but I can’t conceptualise how to do it with gears. I’m trying to map across the concepts.

My question is: **Can you explain in terms of logic gates how Babbage’s Analytical Engine worked?**

Comment: Could you be more specific? One could write a whole book on the subject! (Or try to; this [thread on Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6240/784) suggests that it's not really clear what the design was supposed to be.)

Comment: That sounds like it would be an awesome book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear they're still working out what the design was supposed to be.

Taking an approximation - [they have developed](https://www.fourmilab.ch/babbage/cmdline.html) a Java program to run [sample programs](https://www.fourmilab.ch/babbage/sample.html). The logic behind the source code shows how it [may have](https://www.fourmilab.ch/babbage/authentic.html) worked.